# React - Can't change DOM's Style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to dynamically change my DOM's `height`. But I can't. No errors, console.log prints nothing, just blank with a number indicating how many times this blank line is printed on console. `ref` works but it seems that whatever I write to the `ref` won't be updated to the DOM.

On each keypress, my `resizeTextInput` function is invoked.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      textLen: 0,
      commentError: false,
    };

    this.textInputRef = React.createRef();
    this.commentBlockRef = React.createRef();
    this.resizeTextInput = this.resizeTextInput.bind(this);
    this.handleSearch = this.postComment.bind(this);
    this.postComment = this.postComment.bind(this);
  } 


  resizeTextInput() {
    this.commentBlockRef.current.style.height = 300;
    console.log(this.commentBlockRef.current.style.height);
  }

  postComment(event) {
    this.resizeTextInput();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="comment-wrap">
        <div className={`comment-block ${className}`} ref={this.commentBlockRef}>
          <textarea className={`textarea-${className}`} type="text" placeholder="Write a comment..." onKeyUp={this.postComment} ref={this.textInputRef} size="55" />
          <div className={`comment-block-len ${(commentError || postError) ? 'comment-error' : ''}`}>{textLen}/{MAX_LEN}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a ref for this instead of a CSS class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `300px` in string instead `300` only.

```
this.commentBlockRef.current.style.height = '300px';
```